# gdb: how to get a complete backtrace when fglrx_dri.so segfaults?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, backtrace, ati

I'm experiencing segmentation faults in the fglrx dri library when running my own Qt based OpenGL application. The backtrace I get from gdb (with dbg symbols installed for Qt and my own application):

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0xb7fd9720 (LWP 1809)):
#0  0x06276705 in ?? () from /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/fglrx_dri.so
#1  0x000020dc in ?? ()
#2  0x000020d9 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

I can not see where from my code I call the fglrx function which causes the segmentation fault. How could I extend this backtrace to see it completely from the main() function down to the fglrx dri library?

edit: To confirm my own application is built with debug symbols:

```
Reading symbols from /home/user/fglrx crash/crashtest-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1__Qt-4_8_1__Debug/crashtest...done.
(gdb) br main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804996d: file ../program/main.cpp, line 21.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/fglrx crash/crashtest-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1__Qt-4_8_1__Debug/crashtest  [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff2a4) at ../program/main.cpp:21
21      QApplication a(argc, argv);
(gdb) bt
#0  main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff2a4) at ../program/main.cpp:21
(gdb) n
[New Thread 0xb7d2bb70 (LWP 2475)]
[New Thread 0xb752ab70 (LWP 2476)]
22      QMainWindow w;
(gdb) bt
#0  main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff2a4) at ../program/main.cpp:22
(gdb) s
QFlags<Qt::WindowType>::QFlags (this=0xbffff164) at /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.1/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:2284
2284        Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline QFlags(Zero = 0) : i(0) {}
(gdb) bt
#0  QFlags<Qt::WindowType>::QFlags (this=0xbffff164) at /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.1/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:2284
#1  0x080499a4 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff2a4) at ../program/main.cpp:22
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate debug symbols for your own binary as well. Compile your application with GCC's `-g` option. It's also advisable to turn off optimization for the time of debugging; use GCC's `-O0` flag for this purpose.

Comment: I was already building with debug symbols. I've just recompiled and retested with -O0 instead of -O2 b ut the backtrace stays the same.

Comment: Then this is not the problem! Probably you're messing with function pointers; one of them is corrupted, and the program control goes to a random location, which obviously doesn't match either symbol, so gdb prints ?? for function name. Then it segfaults.

Comment: `fglrx` is a proprietary (AMD CAtalyst) graphical driver, so you probably won't get debugging symbols. You might try the free software equivalent, if you find it.

Comment: @H2CO3 How could I find out at what point during the execution of my program one of the function pointers becomes corrupt? The backtrace I have now doesn't give me any clue.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I should be able to get a full backtrace even if some libraries in between don't have any debug symbols. Switching to the opensource driver makes the crash disappear, but I specifically want to use the fglrx driver.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and awful answer is you can't. [According to Graham Sellers of AMD](https://twitter.com/grahamsellers/status/410504765676613632), the driver is compiled with the [`-fomit-frame-pointer` flag](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fomit-frame-pointer-785), which confuses gdb if it's deeper down the stack.